# href tel tag outputs full page url

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, codeigniter-3

I am experiencing a very unusual output with href tel tag.

**HTML Code Used**

```
<a href="tel:xxxxxxxxxx"><?= $phone; ?></a>
```

**Output**

```
https://example.com/themes/default/tel:xxxxxxxxxx
```

I am using Codeigniter V3 latest.

Output should be **tel:xxxxxxxxx** but it comes out to be https://example.com/themes/default/tel:xxxxxxxxxx

Comment: <a href="http:// tel:xxxxx"> might solve this issue (remember including http://

Comment: @DivyanshSingh Thanks for the reply but this isn't working. When i click it it takes me to a new blank page with address bar " about:blank#blocked "

Comment: That is not reproducible using the info you have given so far. (Works fine, as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/5xpyohue/)